# How to split/get a date of known format from a string in php (pregmatch)

Tags: php

I've got a string, which contains a date with time and i want to convert it to the unix format or something like that, so that i can save it into the database..

It looks always in this form "Mittwoch, 03. August 2011, 09:00 Uhr"

I don't want to write it with string functions but with pregmatch, which i can't use true yet..

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP DateTime class has a method called [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) that should be able to parse the date you have. You can then call `$datetime->format('U');` to get the Unix Timestamp version.

It will only work with PHP > 5.3 however.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\w*,\s+(\d{2})\.\s+(\w*)\s+(\d{4}),\s+,(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $inputString, $matches)

$matches[1] = day of month
$matches[2] = Month
$matches[3] = Year
$matches[4] = Hour
$matches[5] = Minute
```

You can then use mktime/time to convert it.